How to get time zone from autoupdatingCurrentCalendar to update?
This is a follow on question from this question.
I have this test program that I am using to debug a larger cross-language program (Go/Obj-C).
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        const char *tz = [[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] timeZone] name] UTF8String];
        printf("%s\n", tz);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

From the documentation

Settings you get from this calendar do change as the user’s settings change (contrast with currentCalendar).
Note that if you cache values based on the calendar or related information those caches will of course not be automatically updated by the updating of the calendar object.

I would expect running this program and then, while it is running changing the time zone in settings, would result in the printed time zone identifier to follow the changes. This does not happen (Running a single iteration and looping in the shell does work as expected since presumably the program is obtaining an environment at program start). I am not caching anything here.
Is there something that I need to do to make this follow the the current time zone?

I think, without a runloop, the calendar isn't updated. If you just want to get the current time zone then use CFTimeZone.
CFTimeZoneResetSystem();
CFTimeZoneRef timeZone = CFTimeZoneCopySystem();
const char *tz = CFStringGetCStringPtr(CFTimeZoneGetName(timeZone), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFRelease(timeZone);


Thank you. That does what I want. So from what you are saying, we are depending on a system hook via a runloop to update in the approach that I posted above. Is that correct?

Yes, I think the autoupdating calendar isn't polling.

Final query (not an ObjC dev). I need to CFRelease the timeZone. Correct? And since CFStringGetCStringPtr is AFAIUI returning a ref to inside that struct, this will also release//free tz?

Even when I do, this seems to leak.

Sorry, I forgot memory management. timeZone must be released. If a function name contains the word "Get", you do not own the object. Does the test app continue to leak if you let it run a little longer?

It appears to grow monotonically over minutes. I haven't checked for longer periods. I don't know what I should expect in terms of memory management response for ref counted memory here, so I will see if I can get it to crash with OoM.

Watching the memory held by this process shows no indication of reduction. https://gist.github.com/kortschak/a3a12186f3b3a8f6f4c409e92fa3c6f0. Though its slow so I'd have to wait for days for it to crash.

Using Autorelease Pool Blocks might help.

That works perfectly; solid as a rock under 700kb. Thanks.
